# Java 2D chart wont print out

Tags: java, arrays, vector, charts

This is a task for school which i´ve been trying to solve for hours, we are to create a vector chart containting the swedish alphabet in 3 rows and 10 columns. Show the chart and show it reversed in the same space, the alphabet should, it should be a char and not String. As it looks now i get just three columns in the output, so missing most of the alphabet. 
Why is this  happening? And why does it when I instead of using "alpha.length" use 3 and 10 get me an  "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and wont print out the reverse list?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char [][]alpha ={
        {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
        {'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T',},
        {'U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Å','Ä','Ö',},
        };




   for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < alpha.length; j++){
        System.out.print(alpha [i][j] + " ");  
            }
        System.out.println();

            }

      for (int r = alpha.length-1; r >= 0; r--){
        for (int s = alpha.length-1; s >=0; s--){
        System.out.print(alpha[r][s]+ " ");
    }
        System.out.println();


}

} //main
```

Comment: I recommend to read about multidimensional arrays and the IndexOutOfBoundException. You need to understand how to adress each single element, then the error will be a piece of cake.

Comment: `alpha` is an array of `char[]` which contains `alpha.length` (=3) many arrays, each `alpha[i]` is a (different) array of `char` with `alpha[i].length` (10 or so) many `chars`. If you nest your loop you'll have to use the right length.

Comment: Must you really use multidimensional array here?
If I am right, your alphabet contains 29 letters not 30, so have to be careful, you can't use for statements going up to 10 in every case then.
I would store the letters in a single dimensional array. Go through that array and watch if the cycle variable i.e. i divided by ten gives a whole number (i%10==0). If so, insert a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alpha` contains 3 arrays, so its length is 3.
Your code now goes through a 3x3 sized array, that's why it prints only 3 columns (as zapl mentioned in a comment).

Try something like this:

```
...
    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < alpha[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(alpha [i][j] + " ");  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int r = alpha.length-1; r >= 0; r--){
        for (int s = alpha[r].length-1; s >=0; s--){
            System.out.print(alpha[r][s]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
...
```

This way it will go like `alpha[0][0]` (A) then `alpha[0][1]` (B) ... `alpha[0][9]` (J), `alpha[1][0]` (K), `alpha[1][1]` (L) ... `alpha[1][9]` (T), `alpha[2][0]` (U) ... to `alpha[2][8]` (Ö).
And it is the same in reverse order.

Also watch out for commas at the ends of your arrays, you don't need them. (I mean after 'T' and 'Ö').